# Same test class multiple <test> not run

Tags: java, testng

I want to run same test method as part of multiple . TestNG runs my test method only once irrespective. Paramters are different in both cases. Any pointers on how I can achieve this is greatly appreciated

```
public class Test1 extends TestBase{

   @Test
   public void test1(){
      System.out.println("This si test1");
   }

}


public class TestBase {

   @Parameters({ "param1" })
   @BeforeMethod
   public void setup(@Optional("VCHS") String param1) {
      System.out.println("the parameter is "+param1);
   }

   @Parameters({ "param1" })
   @BeforeTest(groups="VC2-UI",alwaysRun=true)
   protected void baseSetUpVC2EndPoint(@Optional("VC2") String param1){
      System.out.println("This is base"+param1);
   }

   @Parameters({ "param1" })
   @BeforeTest(groups="VC1-UI")
   protected void baseSetUpVC1EndPoint(@Optional("VC1") String param1){
      System.out.println("This is base and "+param1);
   }

}

<suite name="Testing" verbose="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">
      <test name="VC2-UI">
      <parameter name="param1"  value="VC2"/>
      <classes>
         <class name="Test1"></class>
      </classes>
   </test>
   <test name="VC1-UI">
      <parameter name="param1"  value="VC1"/>
      <classes>
         <class name="Test1"></class>
      </classes>
   </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: How are you running it ? whatever you have written if you run using the  testng.xml it shjould run test method in test1 class twice wit h different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use invocationCount annotation.

Comment: I am running same test with different parameter here so invocation count is not an option. Data provider also does not suite me as I want to run tests from xml file and want to change the parameter without changing the class.